# PyQt example editabletreemodel.py crashes when the last row is removed

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

In the **editabletreemodel.py** example (from PyQt **examples/itemviews** folder) I noticed that when the last row is removed (e.g. the one reading '**Connection Editing Mode**' or any other after that)  the application crashes with

> 'IndexError: list index out of range'.

Could that be because the example keeps TreeItem objects when indexes are created, etc. instead of ids? I have very similar problem and just wondered whether it is better to keep ids instead of objects? Or it is safe to check whether a row over the limit is requested like this:

```
def child(self, row):
    if row >= self.childCount():
        return None

    return self.childItems[row]
```

I use Python version 2.7.9 and PyQt version '4.9.6'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be reported as a bug on the [pyqt mailing-list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

The original [Qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html) and declares `childItems` as:

```
QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
```

and defines the `child()` function as:

```
TreeItem *TreeItem::child(int number)
{
    return childItems.value(number);
}
```

This doesn't do any explicit bounds-checking, because `value()` will simply return null if `number` is out of bounds. But obviously python lists don't behave in the same way, and so an explicit bounds-check is required:

```
def child(self, row):
    if 0 <= row < self.childCount():    
        return self.childItems[row]
```